# Is there a way to get internal http requests in a Flash object (swf), using C#?

Tags: c#, flash

Is there a way to get internal http requests in a Flash, using C#?

Basically I need analyze all http traffic.

Comment: Maybe explain 'internal' a bit, do you mean you want to see all requests done by flash that do not result in the browser changing to a new page? (And is your swf in a web page?)

Comment: Yes and yes Simon, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) to do Ethernet packet capture from C# (not a pure managed solution), or use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). That's for very sophisticated analysis needs - otherwise a proxy is fine, as suggested by Joel Coehoorn.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to do this is to install a local proxy server such as [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) specifically for that task.